# I Can't add SVN repository in Android Studio

Tags: android, svn, android-studio

I'm trying to add an Subversion (VCS) to Android Studio.
But i have this problem:
[image]
And as you see the configuration of proxy is correct
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the second screenshot shows HTTP proxy that's unrelated to Subversion client and [you should configure HTTP proxy settings for Subversion somewhere else.](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-http-proxy.html)

> To configure proxy settings for Apache Subversion:
>
> 1. Open the Settings dialog box.
> 2. Below the Version Control node, click VCSs, then click Subversion.
> 3. In the Subversion dialog box that opens, click the Edit Network Options button and specify the proxy settings in the Edit Subversion
>      Options Related to Network Layers dialog box that opens.